# Make PowerPoint 2016 slide auto-populate with Excel data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint

I’ll do my best to describe what I’m trying to accomplish. In PowerPoint I have one slide that I need to have auto populate based on data within an excel sheet. I don’t know much about macros except what a macro will achieve.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I've made the title summarize your first question and removed the 2nd part, _"Can you please suggest what I could use to get myself up to speed on macros?"_ as we like a single question per post on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Maybe you would find this video interesting. depending on what you are trying to achieve: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcxHgo8k6CA

Comment: Linking the data from Excel to PowerPoint might be sufficient and would avoid the need for macros.

Comment: @Tina Patel,, I've posted a Non-VBA (Macro) solution will help you to accomplish the Job,, for the same job a Macro can be used also. But I think the show method would be much easier for you !!

Answer (score 0):

**Since you want automatic updation of Excel Tables in Power Point slide and you have only one slide, so that I would like to suggest a Non-VBA method.**

- Create the table in Excel so that it looks exactly the way you will want it to look on the slide, including Titles, Row & Column labels, and others if required.
- Either create a new Power Point file or open the old one and better create proper slide layout to accommodate Data from Excel.
- Copy required part from the table in Excel.
- Now reach to Slide.
- On the Home Tab, click the arrow below the Paste icon to bring up a sub-menu and click on Paste Special.
- In the Paste Special dialog box, select the Paste Link radio button.

**N.B.**

- Remember, to avoid the Data overflow and to accommodate Excel data properly on the Slide, always Copy smaller part like, 10 to 15 Rows and 3 to 5 Columns.
- Paste link supports auto updation so that you could find new values on slide as soon is been updated in Excel.
- If required insert more slides and repeat above shown steps to get Excel data.